# How to fetch all the data from the contact list and send to another activity in a text box in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm new to android. I am creating an application which fetches contacts from contact list in device and send them to other activity. Now the problem is that the code is showing me all the data but while sending to next activity I'm only able to send the number to the next activity in a textbox. So if anyone could help me plz.... Thank you in advance...............

This is my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001; 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getContacts);
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (reqCode) {
                case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    String number = "";
                    try {
                        Uri result = data.getData();

                        //get the id from the uri
                        String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  

                        //query
                        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ? " , new String[] {id}, null);

                        int numberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);  

                        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            number = cursor.getString(numberIdx);
                            Intent i = new Intent(this,Contacts.class);
                            i.putExtra("Contacts",number);
                            startActivity(i);
                        } 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    //failed
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor!=null) {}
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second activity with edittext and button **Contacts.java**

```
public class Contacts extends Activity{
    NfcAdapter adapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    boolean writeMode;
    Tag mytag;
    Context ctx;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_main);
        final EditText data = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        String value1 = super.getIntent().getExtras().getString("Contacts");  
        data.setText(value1);
    }
}
```

Comment: i.putExtra("Contacts",number); OK Fine , like this where are rest details. Correct me if I am wrong , only number is passed so only number is visible

Answer (score 0):

Make a List of names,number,..... and

use `public Intent putExtra (String name, Serializable value)`

pass your list as a parameter